# how I can set countdown to zero when time is over 1h?

Tags: jquery, countdown

I have this code:

```
var czas_isw = new Date(2013, 02-1, 19, 12, 00);

$('.czas_do_rozpoczecia').countdown({until: czas_isw, compact: true, timezone: +1});

$('.czas_trwania').countdown({since: czas_isw, compact: true, timezone: +1});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IdolwSzutrab7/CxdFL/

How I can reset to 0 countdown „#czas_trwania“ when time is over 1h?

Must be „if“, but I know what :/

Answer (score 0):

Surely (glancing *fleetingly* at [the documentation](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html)) you respond to the [`onTick` callback](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#onTick), check how much time is left, and use the [`option` command](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html#optionset) to set a new time?

Comment: yes, mutst be onTick and if, example if ($('.czas_trwania') == +1h) { czas_isw = 0;} :/

Comment: @IdolwSzutrab: No, not `==`, the odds of your getting a callback at that precise *millisecond* are very low. `x <= 3600000` (assuming `x` is in milliseconds).